# Users are deleting my useful answers, what can I do?

Tags: discussion

[Is it possible to translate the Mario example from Elm to either pure JavaFX or to JavaFX+RxJava while preserving the high level abstraction of Elm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795062/is-it-possible-to-translate-the-mario-example-from-elm-to-either-pure-javafx-or/28457453#28457453)

Strange things are happening.  Some of these overactive moderators should chill out and find a better way to channel their anger with life.  I suggest that their moderator status should be removed because they are annoying.  They reduce the value added to SO by deleting good answers.

Comment: How exactly is a link to a youtube video an answer? Have you ever heard the term "link only answer"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to flag an answer as "it is not an answer"?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-it-is-not-an-answer)

Comment: Pro-tip:  Calling a moderator a troll isn't conducive to getting positive responses

Comment: yeah but its not possible to transcribe the content of the video... to put the whole video to SOF...  I mean the link is useful, if it breaks it can be deleted...if it cannot be fixed... then it stops being useful... link only or not, is the point not that the answer gives an anwser? I think that link is super relevant ! and just happens that an expert answers the exact question !

Comment: Then post it as a comment to your question, or even edit the question itself to include it. But it is **not an answer**, and thus should not be posted as an answer.

Comment: `its not possible to transcribe the content of the video` - then it's not suitable for an answer

Comment: @jhegedus The point is that your answer *doesn't* answer the question.  It only tells someone to go somewhere else that may or may not have the answer.  Your SO post should answer the question.  If you want to provide links *in addition* to an answer to the question you can, but a link alone doesn't answer the question.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/165773)** "let me be clear: **this sort of response is *not* an answer**. If you see this, flag it. Moderators, if you see it flagged, *delete it*..."

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your original answer was flagged as being low quality since it was *link-only*, it was [reviewed by the community](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5465986) with the majority of votes to delete it.

I reviewed the result of the community review, I agreed with them that it was link-only so I deleted it. Posting a link to a video isn't a good answer, what happens if the link breaks, then the answer is useless.  Feel free to expand on the link by including an explanation of what's covered in the video or if not, then make it a comment on your question. But, posting it a 2nd time and calling users trolls isn't appropriate.

Comment: yeah but its not possible to transcribe the content of the video... to put the whole video to SOF... I mean the link is useful, if it breaks it can be deleted...if it cannot be fixed... then it stops being useful... link only or not, is the point not that the answer gives an anwser? I think that link is super relevant ! and just happens that an expert answers the exact question !

Comment: No one's asking you to transcribe the whole video. **Just summarize the bit that *answers the question*** - then link to the video as a "for more information" resource if you think it's useful.

Comment: @jhegedus But just posting a link isn't an answer. An answer should be self-contained on this site.  We don't want people searching for similar questions to come here only to be directed everywhere. That's not helpful to anyone.  If you can't summarize the bits here, then make it a comment.

Comment: deleting an useful answer seems to be a very strange emotion based reaction (targeting me personally) so the troll adjective is very appropiate in my opinion... but if that makes people happy... I have better things to do ...  trolls can enjoy trolling around... I go and listen to some good music instead... and chill out... enough nonsense for today :)

Comment: @jhegedus In your opinion it might be useful, but the [community disagrees](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5465986). There is no targeting of you personally. The answer was flagged, the community said it should be deleted, and it was. This happens to everyone, **not just you**. This could be avoided by posting quality content - both questions and answers. But calling other users trolls isn't at all appropriate; this is a community driven site where your actions are reviewed by everyone.

Comment: @jhegedus it simply seems like your definition of "useful" differs from everybody else on SO. People delete it because the answer, on its own, is _not_ useful.

Comment: @jhegedus no one is targetting YOU. people flag your answer, it goes in a queue where some random user (with enough rep so he can be trusted) checks if it's ok or not. Maybe instead of calling people trolls, try to realize that Stack overflow is meant as a self-contained Q & A site. Everyone told you that, and you don't seem to understand it :S

Comment: fine, I get it now, I can be reasoned with, if these are the rules here.... its ok.